# Derive Matlab value matrix from Matlab key matrix and lookup vector

Tags: matlab

I have a Matlab object of integer keys in the range 1:1:7 e.g.

```
[3, 1, 4, 5, 6]
```

I also have a size 7 vector containing an associated value for each integer key, e.g.

```
vals = (10, 20, 30, 4000, 50, 60, 70)
```

what is the most efficient way to create a matrix of the values using the keys as indices, e.g. a matrix

```
[30, 10, 4000, 50, 60]
```

(in reality the key object is 6D). Must I loop?

Comment: Could you explain how `keys` and `vals` are defined for the case of `n` dimensions?

Comment: Edited the question to clarify. The keys object is an n dimensional array consisting only of the integers 1 through seven and the lookup vector is 7 entries total.

Comment: Do you mean `keys` has 6 rows?

Comment: I've updated my answer for the case `key` is a `(3 x 5) array`.

Answer (score 3):

For the case of a 1D matrix a general approach could be:

```
keys=[3, 1, 4, 5, 6];
vals = [10, 20, 30, 4000, 50, 60, 70]
m=vals(keys)
```

With this approach you use the values stored in the `keys` array as indices of the `vals` array. You can find more information about [array insdexing here](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/learn_matlab/array-indexing.html).

In a more general case in which `keys` has `n` rows (3 in the following example):

```
keys=[3, 1, 4, 5, 6;
      1 3 2 4 6 ;
      7 6 5 4 3];
vals = [10, 20, 30, 4000, 50, 60, 70]

m=reshape(vals(keys(:)),size(keys))
```

Hope this helps.

Qapla'

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work. If I got the question.

```
inds = [3, 1, 4, 5, 6];

vals = inds;

vals(vals==1) = 10;
vals(vals==2) = 20;
vals(vals==3) = 30;
vals(vals==4) = 4000;
vals(vals==5) = 50;
vals(vals==6) = 60;
```

Is it like that?

Comment: That is a good way thank you. I can actually loop through it:
    for n = 1:numel(inds)
        vals(vals==n) = inds(n);
    end